# Better way to format a "01234567890" in "012.345.678-90"?

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

I have a simple question about how to format a string.

I have this number as a string **"01234567890"**, with zero on left, and need to format that to be like that "**012.345.678-90**".

I solved it using it

```
char[] charArgs = sCPF.ToCharArray();

return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}.{3}{4}{5}.{6}{7}{8}-{9}{10}", 
                     charArgs[0], charArgs[1], charArgs[2], charArgs[3], 
                     charArgs[4], charArgs[5], charArgs[6], charArgs[7], 
                     charArgs[8], charArgs[9], charArgs[10]);
```

I also tried that :

```
Convert.ToInt64("01234567890").ToString("000.000.000-00")
```

but that gives me **"1234567890,000000-00"**

But if I also tried this

```
Convert.ToInt64("01234567890").ToString("000-000-000-00")
```

which results in "012-345-678-90", but is not what I need in this case, where I need the dots (.).

Are there a better way to do it?

I am using .net 2.0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You were almost there.

Try this:

```
Convert.ToInt64("01234567890").ToString(@"000\.000\.000-00")
```

That gives me: `012.345.678-90`

Comment: I was really almost there. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to convert to int to convert back, and you are sure that the string will follow this format you can do it like this:

```
sCPF = sCPF.Insert(3,".").Insert(7,".").Insert(11,"-");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Convert.ToInt64("01234567890").ToString("000\\.000\\.000-00")
```

Since `.` is defined as a custom format provider you just need to esacape it with a `\`

Comment: This will miss the zero off the front.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with RegExp:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex exp = new Regex(@"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})");
    string s = "01234567890";
     string newS = exp.Replace(s, new MatchEvaluator(doIt));
     newS += "";
}

private string doIt(Match m)
{
    return m.Groups[1] + "." + m.Groups[2] + "." + m.Groups[3] + "-" + m.Groups[4];
}
```

but I'm not sure it looks simpler then your suggestion :-)

Answer (score -6):

Need to do `StringName.PadLeft(11)`

Comment: What is `StringName`? Why `PadLeft`? What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: as in `String StringName = "01234567890";`

Comment: Which doesn't appear _anywhere_ in the question or explained in your answer.

Comment: Nor does it come close to answering the question.